# iterate of df colomns to give rows with text

Tags: pandas, list, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with columns. The columns have mostly blank rows but a few of the rows have strings and those are the only rows i want to see. I have tried the below code but dont know how to only select strings in the columns and append to get a new dataframe with only columns with strings in the rows.

```
columns = list(df) 

for i in columns: 

    df1 = df[df[i]== ]
```

can someone please help?

Comment: Assuming that the blank values are filled as NA's, you can use `df.dropna()`. See documentation here for whether you want to drop rows or columns based on the presence of NAs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[df['column_name'].isna()]
```

should do the trick